# How to bind response data to view in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, httpresponse

I was trying display an image at  element but it is not working, And when i'm simply returning the data its displaying image.

route.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard',function() {

       $Image = Auth::user()->profile_pic;
       $type = 'image/jpeg';
       $img = response($Image)->header('Content-Type', $type);

       return View::make('dashboard', ['img'=>$img]);
     });
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
<img src={{ $img }} class="img-circle" width="200" height="200">
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a route so that when a request is sent to the specified URL, the avatar is read from the DB and sent to the browser, as image/jpeg.

E.g. Add the following code to your `routes.php`

```
Route::any('/user/{user}/profile-pic',
    function(\App\User $user) {
       $Image = Auth::user()->profile_pic;
       return response($Image)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    });
```

modify the /dashboard route to make use of this new route

```
Route::get('/dashboard',function() {
       $id = Auth::user()->id;
       $imageUrl="/user/$id/profile-pic";
       return view('/dashboard', ['imageUrl' => $imageUrl]);
     });
```

finally, in your view, bind the new variable

```
<img src="{{$imageUrl}}" class="img-circle" width="200" height="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `Auth::user()->profile_pic` the URL of user's avatar?
If so, just use

```
return View::make('dashboard', ['img'=>Auth::user()->profile_pic]);
```

Also, add quotes to src attribute:

```
<img src="{{ $img }}" class="img-circle" width="200" height="200">
```

It's important to know that

```
$img = response($Image)->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

is a response object which is `Illuminate\Http\Response`, but in the HTML you need a link to the image, a `string`, instead of a `Response`

Comment: Any error messages? Right click and view page source, what HTML have you got?

Comment: If u can, please check source on https://github.com/Jatinbalodhi96/Laravel-Blogger-Application

Comment: <img src="class=&quot;img-circle&quot;" width="200" height="200"> showing this on html

Comment: there is still no address in html

Comment: I see, profile_pic is a BLOB in your database schema. Storing pictures as a BLOB, although doable, is not a good practice. It's better to store the image url in the database, and image itself on the file system. See my other answer for solution